# How can I copy a 2D array and add a new row to store the sum of the columns in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Basically I have a function that receives a two dimensional array, adds an extra row and then calculates the sum of the columns and stores the results for each individual column in the extra row that was created earlier. Here is my code:

```
public static int[][] sum(int[][] array) {
    int tempArray[][] = new int[array.length + 1][array[0].length];

    for (int column = 0; column < tempArray[0].length; column++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < tempArray.length; row++) {
            total += tempArray[row][column];
        }

        tempArray[tempArray.length][column] = total;

    }

    return tempArray;
}
```

---

So when I run a for loop to print the results I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error for some reason that refers to the function. I think my logic is correct but I can't seem to make it work. For some more context the values for the array are entered by the user. Thank you whoever will answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds because you are accessing the index more than the bound of array in the below line:

```
tempArray[tempArray.length][column] = total;
```

Replace it with following the line would solve your problem:

```
tempArray[tempArray.length - 1][column] = total;
```

However your code still won't work as your summation logic have bug. You are calculating the total by the following line.

```
total += tempArray[row][column];
```

But your tempArray doesn't have any value but zeros. To solve this make sure you initiate the tempArray by the values of array's like following:

```
int tempArray[][] = new int[array.length + 1][array[0].length];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
        tempArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised the `tempArray[][]`.

`tempArray[tempArray.length][column] = total`

change it to

`tempArray[tempArray.length-1][column] = total`

this will resolve the index out of bound issue.

```
public static int[][] sum(int[][] array) {
    int tempArray[][] = new int[array.length + 1][array[0].length];

    for (int column = 0; column < array[0].length; column++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            tempArray[row][column] = array[row][column];
            total += array[row][column];
        }

        tempArray[tempArray.length-1][column] = total; // resolves the index out of bound issue

    }

    return tempArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned solutions will not work in case if rows have different length. For example, if input array is

```java
int[][] input = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3 } };
```

This solution eliminates such problem

```java
public static int[][] sum(int[][] array) {
    int[][] tempArray = new int[array.length + 1][];

    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length);

        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, array[i].length);
    }

    tempArray[tempArray.length - 1] = new int[maxLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++ ) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int[] row : tempArray) {
            if (i <= row.length - 1) {
                total += row[i];
            }
        }
        tempArray[tempArray.length - 1][i] = total;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

And the test

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 3 } };
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sum(arr))); 
    // Output
    // [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5, 3]]
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. Under what circumstances would one require an array with varying length rows?

Comment: Well, maybe author tries to launch this program on Tetris and he's very limited in memory, so here is no trailing zeros :) Seriously, the author does not describe the subject area, so the most general solution must be implied.

Comment: @Abra I have to make a program that calculates the expenses by categorie of a family and returns the results back into the original array. The values were entered originally into an array by the user. This is what the teacher wanted. Trust me this is not my choice. Lol